# Use Selenium to fill the username and password on this site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use an auto-login feature on Python by opening the website via a GUI. I am able to open the website ("https://iam.bethel.edu") without any issues. I know with Selenium you can choose to manipulate the site to fill the username/password boxes (one of the guys I used to intern with did it).

However, I can't seem to put text into the username or password fields because I keep getting a `NoSuchElementException`. Am I just missing something with the `find_element()` method?

My Code:

```
def open_IAM(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='.\ChromeDriver.exe')

        driver.get("https://iam.bethel.edu")
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "input-box").send_keys('username', Keys.TAB, 'password!', Keys.ENTER)
```

Other code that works with the Instagram site:

```
browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys('MYEMAIL', Keys.TAB, 'MYPW', Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `username` and `password` elements are embedded in `iframe`. so in order to interact with those elements, you have to switch to that `iframe`.

Here is a very rough code snippet.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class Login:
    def __init__(self, username, pwd):
        self.username = username
        self.pwd = pwd
        self.url = 'https://iam.bethel.edu/idmdash/#/default'
        self.chromeDriver_dir = r"Your chrome exe dir" # put in your value
        self.iframe_id = 'oauthframe' # fixed don't change
        self.uname_id = 'Ecom_User_ID'# fixed don't change

    def _launch_website(self):
        self.chrome = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(self.chromeDriver_dir))
        self.chrome.maximize_window()
        self.chrome.get(self.url)

    def _switch_iframe(self): # this is the part you should add to your code
        iframe = WebDriverWait(self.chrome, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, self.iframe_id)))
        self.chrome.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    def _input_username_pwd(self):
        uname = WebDriverWait(self.chrome, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, self.uname_id)))
        login_chain = ActionChains(self.chrome)
        login_chain.click(uname).send_keys(self.username).send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        login_chain.send_keys(self.pwd).perform()

    def login(self):
        self._launch_website()
        self._switch_iframe()
        self._input_username_pwd()
        time.sleep(20) # Just to ensure everything worked. 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Login(username='ABC', pwd='EFG').login()
```

Comment: Perfect, I will take a look at some of this code over the weekend and see if it is the fix! Looks to make logical sense though!